# Working with multilevel lists in WORD 365, numbers are rendered as a black rectangle

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

When I save a document (I am using office 365 on a MAC), the user defined style for level 2 turns the numbering to a black box.  None of the fixes suggested in this forum fix the problem.  It occurs on numerous documents even though I have updated the style in the normal template.

I have tried deleting all the styles and re-importing from the normal template because it corrupts the style in the style bar, not just in the body of the document. What is also odd is that, in a multilevel list, the preceding and following number formats are correct.  It happens mostly in list level 2. I have a screen capture which shows the section header and the black bar where the number should be. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VIg0.png)  Incidentally, I just updated to the 64bit version of office 365 and it just did it again.  I wonder if it is a compatibility issue between office versions -the original styles were made in documents built in MAC 2011 version of office.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried deleting all the styles and re-importing from the normal template.  I have a screen capture but don't see how to add it here.